# Is there an "on debug finished" activation event for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to activate my extension when the debug session has ended. Is there an activation event for this? I couldn't find one [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onDebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug

`onDidTerminateDebugSession` might be what you want.

> An event which fires when a debug session has terminated.

Comment: Ah thanks! Sorry, I assumed it would be under activiation events, as I simply need to run some code when debugging ends. Any advice on when to activate my extension?

Comment: I usually go with `"onStartupFinished"`.  Then listen to that `onDidTerminateDebugSession` event and do whatever it is you want to do.  There isn't a way to activate based on the debug session termination.  You have to be activated already to listen for it.  But it looks like you can do the same thing with the `"onDebug"` activationEvent.  I'm guessing you wouldn't be doing much on activation other than setting up the termination listener.